# Connect remotely to a server

Tags: server, samba, ftp

I have set up both a ftp and a smb server in my Xubuntu, and I would like to know how to remotely connect to the server as in outside of the home I set the server in

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you would like to do, just use ssh by typing `ssh ip` but replace ip with the ip of the device. If that is not working for you you can also download Putty from [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) which is a GUI ssh program.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "noip.com". Your IP address is more than likely dynamic. With "noip.com" you can use their client to keep your dynamic IP address updated to an easily readable Domain Name Server(DNS). Then as Ray said you can `ssh $YourDNS` to access your servers shell. You can also use an FTP client like FileZilla to access your FTP server again with your DNS instead of the IP address. As for samba access it would probably just be easier to install and configure OpenVPN then you can access samba as if it is on the same local network.